# Uninstalling msi installation with patches

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, msp, msi-patch

I have a product installation that has been patched with one small update patch which is uninstallable. Is there any difference if I first uninstall the patch and then product installation or if I select the uninstall of the product while the patch is still installed? Product and patch installations are created using WiX tools.

Answer (score 3):

The final result of both ways to uninstall is the same - the product is uninstalled. However, you might potentially face with other problems in the first case, when you first uninstall a patch, then the product.

I would recommend you to get acquainted with [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/09/12/how-patching-works.aspx) to understand how it all works. The end of the page mentions uninstallable patches. Afterwards, be sure to check other Heath's blog posts about patching, like:

- [Source Resolution during Patch Uninstall](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/12/08/source-resolution-during-patch-uninstall.aspx)
- [How to Safely Delete Orphaned Patches](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/01/31/how-to-safely-delete-orphaned-patches.aspx)
- [Uninstallable Patches that are not Uninstallable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/06/21/uninstallable-patches-that-are-not-uninstallable.aspx)

Finally, you might want to browse [other "installation" posts on that blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/tags/installation/) - it contains lots of useful info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I asked this question because it seems that my small update patch somehow always stays orphaned after I uninstall the product installation. Is there something else besides failed installation that causes patch to become orphaned?

Comment: I suspect there is a number of reasons apart from the failed installation. However, I don't have enough knowledge to explain the bits and pieces. I strongly suggest you read the first article in the answer above and project it to your solution. When I had a strange problem with patches (don't remember exactly what it was), the low-level explanation how it all works (like in the article above) helped a lot!